# How can I represent this set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a set of variables: $X := \{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$

Let the range for each variable $x_i$ be $R_i$.

How can I represent the set $\{(x_i, v_i), \forall x_i \in X, \forall v_i \in R_i \}$  in terms of $X$ and $R_i, i =1, \ldots, n$?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for? Why isn't what you've written acceptable?

Comment: $\bigcup_{i=1}^n\{x_i\}\times R_i$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen thanks. Now it is in terms of $R_i$'s. Can it be further written in terms of $X$ and $R_i$'s, without explicitly mentioning $x_i$?

Comment: @Tim why not use the notation $R_x$ for the range of the variable $x$? Then you can write
$$
\bigcup_{x \in X} \{x\}\times R_x
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: That works. Can it be further written without explicitly writing element $x$ of $X$?

Comment: @Tim I don't think you can do better than that